# how to update 'people/me'

Tags: google-api-js-client, google-people-api

i use

```
people.get({resourceName: 'people/me'})
```

get logged-in user's info, but i can't use

```
people.updateContact({resourceName: 'people/me', ...})
```

or

```
people.updateContact({resourceName: 'people/[meid]', ...})
```

update this info.

error message is :

```
{code: 400, message: "Resource name "people/me" is not a valid contact person resource.", status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"}
```

or

```
{code: 400, message: "Resource name "people/[meid]" is not a valid contact person resource.", status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't support for updating the `people/me` resource in the `Google People API` as the API only supports updating contacts, and `people/me` represents the person based on your profile / account. There's some info describing how merged people are composed at https://developers.google.com/people/#understanding_merged_person_data. Only contact based people can be updated.

Comment: Thank you, GAPI is there any other api provided to support this operation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the name which you get by your first line.

e.g.

```
people.updateContact({resourceName: 'Name which you got in response', ...})
```